# Find a global minimum for $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}$ under contains $\sum_{i=1}^n x_ia_i^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find a global minimum for $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}$ under contains $\sum_{i=1}^n x_ia_i^2=1$ for $x_i, a_i > 0$ $(\forall 1 \leq i \leq n)$.

Applying Lagrange multiplier theorem we get one point: $\frac{1}{a_1\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}, \dots, \frac{1}{a_n\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}$. 
We can show that $f \rightarrow\infty$ when $x \rightarrow 0$, so the global minimum isn't near zero.
Intuition says that there are no more options for a global minimum, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: What do you mean $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac{1}{x_1},\dots,\frac{1}{x_n}$?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Any other local minima/maxima would have to satisfy the Lagrange equation, but you found the only point that does. So you just need to check that your function doesn't get arbitrarily small (negative) close to the boundary (which would mean there is no global minimum), but you did check that by showing $f \to \infty$ if any of the $x_i \to 0$. (Note: I didn't check whether the solution you got from the Lagrange equation is correct or not.)

Comment: Thanks @kccu. I understand intuitively why 0 is the only boundary point that matters. But how can I prove it?

Comment: Imagine what the constraint looks like. If $n=2$, it's just $x_1a_1^2+x_2a_2^2=1$, $x_1,x_2>0$, which is an (open) line segment. Its boundary corresponds to when $x_1=0$ or $x_2=1$. If $n=3$, you have $x_1a_1^2+x_2a_2^2+x_3a_3^2=1$, $x_1,x_2,x_3>0$, which is an (open) triangle. Again, its boundary corresponds to when one of the $x_i$ is zero. We can't really picture it in higher dimensions, but the fact that you have specified $x_i>0$ means the boundaries are precisely when one or more of the $x_i$ is $0$.

Comment: I see it now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective function is convex because it is a sum of convex functions (for $x_i > 0$). The constraint is affine. Hence the problem satisfies the assumptions of a convex minimisation problem: the global minimum is unique.